Add app name as value to page title in Blazor
I’d like to add a custom value to the page title in my Blazor app.
I’m currently using the native <title></title> component which doesn’t pass any values other than each pages name.
I’d like to have a page title convention like this:
App name | page name

You can create your Custom component for title. Here's how you can do that.

Create a RazorComponent inside your application with below code.

<title>App Name | @Title</title>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
}


Then you can use this component to set the title like this.

@page "/"
<CustomPageTitle Title="Page 1"></CustomPageTitle>

<h1>Hello World</h1>


You will get the required result.



I've been trying this already. Unfortuantly, it only works at a per page level, and not at a sitewide level when added to the main layout template. :(

I've also been trying a cascadingParameter, which I can't get to work either.
I believe the issue is because the <title> tag is loaded above the <body> content when each page's content is rendered in the template.
Therefore, a descendent parameter at the page level would need to be inhirited back up to the layout template.

I've got it working by creating a component that contains the sitename as a string:
sitename.razor
app name
Then included this custom component within the native PageTitle component:


    Page name

Not ideal I know. There ust be a way to pass the site name down to other pages...?

You should use Per page level approach. As the page name isn't going to change again and again.

Your approach means adding the app name on every single page individually.
My solution, means adding the app name to a component and adding that to each page. The difference is, I only need to edit/update to app name once in the component and it will update accross ALL pages.

I think you have mis judged my solution. In my approach you only have to define appname once but the for each page you have to define page name. you can recheck my approach.
